# How can I draw on a canvas that is on a Boostrap modal without it giving me incorrect heights while scrolling

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, canvas, bootstrap-modal

I have a canvas for drawing on a bootstrap modal. I had to account for the height and width of the modal on the screen and it mostly works ([see jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/markm208/ajagmabb/2/)).

The problem is when I scroll down in the modal all of my Y values are off (you will have to scroll down in the modal and attempt to draw to see the odd behavior). How do I account for scrolling in a bootstrap modal?

```
//store the old current mouse position and the previous mouse position
previousMousePosition.x = currentMousePosition.x;
previousMousePosition.y = currentMousePosition.y;

//attempting to account for the bootstrap modal here!!!
//get the modal divs child- the bootstrap modal
var modalDialog = commentPictureModal.children[0];
//get the content div
var modalContent = modalDialog.children[0];
//get the header and the body of the modal from the content div
var modalHeader = modalContent.children[0];
var modalBody = modalContent.children[1];
//get the height of the header
var modalHeaderHeight = modalHeader.clientHeight + modalContent.clientTop;

//get the new mouse position 
currentMousePosition.x = e.pageX - (commentCanvas.offsetLeft + modalDialog.offsetLeft);
currentMousePosition.y = e.pageY - (commentCanvas.offsetTop + modalDialog.offsetTop + modalHeaderHeight);
```

Comment: Is using `absolute` positioning on your modal an option?

Comment: You can use `getBoundingClientRect`: https://jsfiddle.net/7eL2jdz2/1/